# JPA Sequence Generator causing ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column for Id column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using sequence generator (type long) to generate the sequence. But it throws "ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column". When I delete the Sequence generator annotation from my Entity class it works fine with hard coded user id. Note:all other values for different columns remain same.

```
[1/3/14 12:04:41:886 IST] 00000033 SystemOut     O Hibernate: select              FACILITY_MAPPING_SEQ.nextval from dual
[1/3/14 12:04:42:194 IST] 00000033 SystemOut     O Hibernate: insert into FACILITY_MAPPING (ACCESS_SYSTEM_LOCATION_NAME, CD_HOME_LOCATION_NAME, CREATED_BY, CREATION_DATE, DEPARTMENT_ID, FACILITY_ID, SYSTEM_TGAD, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATED_BY, FACILITY_MAPPING_PK) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[1/3/14 12:04:42:115 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R 6348489 [WebContainer : 3] INFO org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl - ignoreXmlConfiguration == true
[1/3/14 12:04:42:874 IST] 00000033 JDBCException W org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions SQL Error: 1438, SQLState: 22003
[1/3/14 12:04:42:887 IST] 00000033 JDBCException E org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
[1/3/14 12:04:42:887 IST] 00000033 JDBCException W org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions SQL Error: 1438, SQLState: 22003
[1/3/14 12:04:42:888 IST] 00000033 JDBCException E org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
[1/3/14 12:04:42:899 IST] 00000033 RegisteredSyn E   WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1321)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$3.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.CallbackCoordinator.beforeCompletion(CallbackCoordinator.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.HibernateSynchronizationImpl.beforeCompletion(HibernateSynchronizationImpl.java:51)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredSyncs.coreDistributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:291)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.prePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:2338)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:557)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1015)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:438)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit(TranStrategy.java:950)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:579)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4873)
    at com.swissre.bae.shared.services.EJSLocal0SLAddNewFacilityServiceImpl_0f22d836.getUpdateAddNewFacility(EJSLocal0SLAddNewFacilityServiceImpl_0f22d836.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.proxy.EjbBeanProxyHandler.invoke(EjbBeanProxyHandler.java:204)
    at org.javassist.tmp.java.io.Serializable_$$_javassist_18.getUpdateAddNewFacility(Serializable_$$_javassist_18.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:551)
    at com.swissre.bae.server.rpc.BAEController.processCall(BAEController.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3751)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.CallbackCoordinator.beforeCompletion(CallbackCoordinator.java:117)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

My FacilityMapping class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FACILITY_MAPPING")
public class FacilityMapping implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1977735642805030781L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FACILITYMAPPINGPKSEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="FACILITYMAPPINGPKSEQ", sequenceName = "FACILITY_MAPPING_SEQ")
    @Column(name="FACILITY_MAPPING_PK")
    private long faciltiyMappingPk;

    @Column(name="SYSTEM_TGAD")
    private String systemTGAD;

    @Column(name="CD_HOME_LOCATION_NAME")
    private String cdHomeLocationName;

    @Column(name="ACCESS_SYSTEM_LOCATION_NAME")
    private String accSysLocName;

    @Column(name="FACILITY_ID")
    private long facilityId;

    @Column(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private long departmentId;

    @Column (name="CREATION_DATE")
    private Date creationDate;

    @Column (name="UPDATE_DATE")
    private Date updateDate;

    @Column (name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column (name="UPDATED_BY")
    private String updatedBy;

    public long getFaciltiyMappingPk() {
        return faciltiyMappingPk;
    }

    public void setFaciltiyMappingPk(long faciltiyMappingPk) {
        this.faciltiyMappingPk = faciltiyMappingPk;
    }

    public String getSystemTGAD() {
        return systemTGAD;
    }

    public void setSystemTGAD(String systemTGAD) {
        this.systemTGAD = systemTGAD;
    }

    public String getCdHomeLocationName() {
        return cdHomeLocationName;
    }

    public void setCdHomeLocationName(String cdHomeLocationName) {
        this.cdHomeLocationName = cdHomeLocationName;
    }

    public String getAccSysLocName() {
        return accSysLocName;
    }

    public void setAccSysLocName(String accSysLocName) {
        this.accSysLocName = accSysLocName;
    }

    public long getFacilityId() {
        return facilityId;
    }

    public void setFacilityId(long facilityId) {
        this.facilityId = facilityId;
    }

    public long getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(long departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }



    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Date getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }
}
```

Please suggest some help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can probably increase the precision of `FACILITY_MAPPING_PK` say from Number(10) to Number(15). Check the value of FACILITY_MAPPING_SEQ.nextval and choose your new precision accordingly.

Comment: kindly check the FACILITY_MAPPING_SEQ.nextval value and DB column size.

Comment: Hi Thiyaga,size of the FACILITY_MAPPING_PK is NUMBER(3).And the FACILITY_MAPPING_SEQ is returning value accordingly e,g 121,122 etc.

Hi Suresh,
the size of DB column is Number(3) and the return value from FACILITY_MAPPING_SEQ.nextval is 2 digit values only  e.g 121,122 etc

Thanks both of you

Answer (score 0):

By your exception's stack trace,  any of your inserting value is above the precision defined on DB column.

And most probable it will be with value generated by sequence. Just check what next value your sequence generating and increase the size a/c to that.